# Generic type instantiation in Factory class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have this structure

```
public class Base<T>
{

}

public class A : Base<string>
{

}

public class B : Base<int>
{

}

public class Factory
{
    public Base<T> GetInstance<T>(int type)
    {
        if (type == 0)
            return new A();
        else
            return new B();
    }
}
```

but I get compile error about `Cannot convert expression type B to return type Base<T>`, why I get this error? and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling your factory?

Comment: This doesn't work because `A` and `B` don't derive from the same base type (except `Object`), as `Base<string>` and `Base<int>`are unrelated in the inheritance hierarchy (except for sharing `Object` as a same base class); to my understanding, this cannot be fixed directly.

Comment: Your code is not generic - you are returning a specific type based on certain input that has nothing to do with that type.  The point of generics is to work with _any_ type the client chooses (subjects to defined constraints).

Comment: @StephenBrickner it is compile time error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why I get this error?

You are getting this error because the compiler cannot verify at compile time that `T` is `string` when `type` is `0` or that `T` is `int` otherwise. As far as the compiler is concerned, `T` could be any type.

> and how can I fix it?

You need to cast the result to `Base<T>` like this:

```
public class Factory
{
    public Base<T> GetInstance<T>(int type)
    {
        if (type == 0)
            return new A() as Base<T>;
        else
            return new B() as Base<T>;
    }
}
```

Which will cause this method to return `null` if `T` is not the correct type.

The following alternative will throw a `InvalidCastException` exception if `T` is not the correct type:

```
public class Factory
{
    public Base<T> GetInstance<T>(int type)
    {
        if (type == 0)
            return (Base<T>)(object)new A();
        else
            return (Base<T>)(object)new B();
    }
}
```

Another approach that might work for you (depending on your requirements) is to remove the `type` parameter and to depend completely on `T` to determine the type of object that you need to return. Here is an example:

```
public Base<T> GetInstance<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        return (Base<T>)(object)new A();
    else if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        return (Base<T>)(object)new B();

    throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported type T");
}
```

Comment: While this may work syntactically (hence +1), I can't see the point of it; the desired type would explicitly have to be known by the caller, hence the factory would not provide a real abstraction.

Comment: Is it possible to use constraints to guide compiler? `where T: Base<T>` (not sure how)?

Comment: @Codor, I am simply explaining to OP why the compiler is complaining, and giving him a direct answer of how to fix it.

Comment: @Sinatr, I don't think you can do that

Comment: @YacoubMassad I didn't mean to come across harshly; my apologies if I did. In fact, your answer is very comprehensive. I just wanted to point out that perhaps the OP's desired result is not a real solution of the actual problem.

Comment: @Codor, that is why I answered a direct answer. We don't really know what OP really wants until maybe he comments on the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your method is not generic because you're returning a non-generic type based on the type that's passed in (whether you use a code for the type or the actual type).  *At best* you could define a relationship between the type passed in and the return type:

```
public Base<T> GetInstance<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        return new A() as Base<T>;
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        return new B() as Base<T>;
    throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported type: " + typeof(T).ToString());
}
```

But type checking and branching in a generic method is generally a code smell. A safer option would be to have different methods:

```
public Base<int> GetIntInstance()
{
    return new A();
}
public Base<string> GetStringInstance()
{
    return new B();
}
```

Note that

- The number of lines of code is the same (less if you don't count brackets)
- The calling syntax is almost identical (`GetIntInstance` vs `GetInstance<int>`)
- There is no risk of using an unsupported generic type argument